# Concatenating a char to a string in a loop?

Tags: java

So I'm trying to do as the title says, but I'm having a hard time getting my code to concatenate the characters to a different string. So far I've gotten it to loop through each character and shift it +1 so "a" becomes "b". Any time I try concatenating the char variable c to string variable finish it throws me an error saying that it can't convert char to string.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
char c;
String finish = "";
System.out.print("Text me: ");
String text = input.next();
String lowercase = text.toLowerCase();

for (int i = 0; i < lowercase.length(); i++){

    c = lowercase.charAt(i);
    System.out.println(++c);

}
System.out.println(finish);
System.out.println(lowercase);
```

Any tips?

Thanks.

Comment: *Any time I try concatenating the char variable c to string variable finish it throws me an error saying that it can't convert char to string* - Impossible, you can concatenate every kind of variable to a string. How are you doing it? Post the full code.

Comment: There's no concatenation in your code.

Comment: The code in your question works fine. Are you missing some code that wasn't posted in your question?

Comment: Inside the for loop, just add `finish += ++c;` (instead of the System.out-line); that will do your concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot. So initially I was trying to use the .concat() way of concatenating the char c to the string finish with each iteration of the loop. It looked something like finish = finish.concat(c); and it was causing an error saying I couldn't convert char to string.

Then I changed it to this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
char c;
String finish = "";
System.out.print("Text me: ");
String text = input.next();
String lowercase = text.toLowerCase();

for (int i = 0; i < lowercase.length(); i++){
  c = lowercase.charAt(i);
  System.out.println(++c);
  finish = finish + c;
}
System.out.println(finish);
```

The only changes I made were adding the last line finish = finish + c; at the end of the loop and removing the bit at the end that printed string lowercase.

Also I don't have formatting/etiquette figured out yet here, so I apologize if what I'm doing looks wonky or doesn't make sense.

Comment: FYI, you can shorten it to `finish += c;`. Also, you should generally avoid string concatenation in loops. Consider using a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check the [Stringbuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), I think this will suit your needs better.

Also keep in mind to close the scanner with `input.close()`